# Dota 2 api number of matches

Tags: steam-web-api

I need a link to get number all matches in dota 2 and number winned matches.

I use http://api.steampowered.com/IPlayerService/GetRecentlyPlayedGames/v0001/?key=[YOURAPIKEY]&steamid=[STEAMID]&format=json
but result is:

```
{
    "response": {
        "total_count": 1,
        "games": [
            {
                "appid": 570,
                "name": "Dota 2",
                "playtime_2weeks": 2273,
                "playtime_forever": 197614,
                "img_icon_url": "0bbb630d63262dd66d2fdd0f7d37e8661a410075",
                "img_logo_url": "d4f836839254be08d8e9dd333ecc9a01782c26d2"
            }
        ]

    }
}
```

number all matches not detected :(

Answer (score 2):

This is not the correct API to use for this kind off query. [A very quick Google search](https://www.google.ie/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#sourceid=chrome-psyapi2&ie=UTF-8&q=dota%202%20api) indicates that [something like this](http://dev.dota2.com/showthread.php?t=47115) is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

What does "number all matches in dota 2" and "winned matches" mean? I think you should make your question more clear.

The following page provides a list of dota2 web APIs, you should check it first:
[Things You Should Know Before Starting API Development](https://dev.dota2.com/showthread.php?t=58317). It seems valve doesn't provide that API for total played Dota 2 games.

And I suppose that "won matches" should refer to "Radiant won matches" since there is always a winner in Dota 2 matches. You could visit some Dota 2 stats websites like [dotabuff](https://www.dotabuff.com/) for the answer.